# Why do mage.exe need administrative privileges to access certificate, but signtool.exe do not

Tags: powershell, continuous-integration, pfx, mage

I'm making a CI build task in PowerShell to sign an assembly and the manifest with signtool and mage.

It works great, except that I have to run PowerShell as Administrator to get mage to accept the certificate. What I find really strange is that signtool can use the same certificate without privileges.

The certificate is a .pfx file.

#### Script:

```
signtool sign /f $certPath /p $certPassword /q /t $timestampUri "Example.dll"
mage -s "Example.dll.manifest" -CertFile $certPath -Password $certPassword -ti $timestampUri
```

#### Without privileges:

```
Done Adding Additional Store
Successfully signed and timestamped: Example.dll
Unable to open certificate "D:\example.pfx":
Access denied.
```

#### With privileges:

```
Done Adding Additional Store
Successfully signed and timestamped: Example.dll
Example.dll.manifest successfully signed
```

Does anyone know what is going on here?

#### Edit:

I used Procmon as adviced. Log below in CSV
[Procmon logs](https://pastebin.com/RHRDTCnU)

Comment: Use [ProcMon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to see what's generating errors. Is the certificate in root dir? Just a hunch; try and move it into a subdir. Root dirs have quirky permissions.

Comment: Good suggestion, but I tried it now and got the same result on my machine

Comment: If moving doesn't work, use Procmon like vonPryz said. Have it filter on `signtool` and `mage` and only enable the `file` filter to not get overwhelmed by what it's outputting. If you can post the results, people will help you analyze it.

Comment: Thanks.  I tried to use Procmon now and posted the result in a link above. I don't have experience with analyzing this, but "FILE LOCKED WITH ONLY READERS" popped out immediately.

Comment: I can't see any problem with the trace you've posted. I was hoping to get an Access Denied message in the output. Can you run procmon again without disabling any filter?